# GetX flutter state is not being updated

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-getx

I am new to flutter. I just started using GetX flutter package. I am working on a ToDo list app. I am having trouble updating the widget state. What I have done is I have created an **AddTaskController** that updates the listView state whenever **Add item** button is clicked. Each list item contains a checkbox. The issue is that I am unable to update the state of list item on click of checkbox.
Here's the code:
**AddTaskController**

```
class AddTaskController extends GetxController {

  RxList<TaskItem> toDoTasksList = RxList([]);

  addTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.add(taskItem);
  }

  removeTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.remove(taskItem);
  }
}
```

**AddTaskScreen**

- AddTaskButton

```
    ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {
        TaskItem taskItem = TaskItem(
          taskStatus: TASK_STATUS.TODO,
          isChecked: false,
          taskName: title,
        );
        addTaskController.addTask(taskItem);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      label: Text('Add Item'),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

- ListView

```
    Expanded(
      child: Obx(
        () => ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TaskCheckItem(
              value: addTaskController.toDoTasksList[index].isChecked,
              title: addTaskController.toDoTasksList[index].taskName,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                print(newValue);
                addTaskController.toDoTasksList[index].setChecked(newValue);
              },
              onDownloadClicked: () {},
              onDeleteClicked: () {},
            );
          },
          itemCount: addTaskController.toDoTasksList.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Which one do you recommend? Provider? Also, can you please tell me why I should not use GetX?

Comment: you do update the list but you didn't send any value to check box. so the checkbox and also the list item didn't find out there are any changes in the parent widget.
here  addTaskController.toDoTasksList[index].setChecked(newValue); you update the list but dont send this to  TaskCheckItem ,

Comment: Why not use getx? Why is the hate with Getx?

Answer (score 3):

Update the Type for the list in AddTaskController

```
class AddTaskController extends GetxController {

  final toDoTasksList = Rx<List<TaskItem>>([]);

  addTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.value.add(taskItem);
  }

  removeTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.value.remove(taskItem);
  }
}
```

*No changes needed in AddTaskButton

Update the callback in your ListView so the state is updated

```
    Expanded(
      child: Obx(
        () => ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TaskCheckItem(
              value: addTaskController.toDoTasksList.value[index].isChecked,
              title: addTaskController.toDoTasksList.value[index].taskName,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                print(newValue);
                // call update() when changing state of list object
                addTaskController.toDoTasksList.update((value) {
                  value![index].setChecked(newValue);
                },
              },
              onDownloadClicked: () {},
              onDeleteClicked: () {},
            );
          },
          itemCount: addTaskController.toDoTasksList.value.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This [note](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#note-about-lists) regarding Get State Management and Lists may be helpful

Comment: You saved my day, thank you ❤️❤️

Answer (score 2):

to update the state you have to add to the value of the list
`toDoTasksList.add(taskItem);` this will not update the state

`toDoTasksList.value.add(taskItem);` this will update the state

if it didn't work instead of using `RxList<TaskItem> toDoTasksList = RxList([]);`

just use `RxList<TaskItem> toDoTasksList = <TaskItem>[].obs;`

i hope  this helps you

Answer (score 2):

Always call refresh() method after updating value of Rx variables.

Instead of this

```
  addTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.add(taskItem);
  }

  removeTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.remove(taskItem);
  }
```

Try this,

```
  addTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.add(taskItem);
    toDoTaskList.refresh();     //<----- refresh() call
}

  removeTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    toDoTasksList.remove(taskItem);
     toDoTaskList.refresh();    //<----- refresh() call
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call update() in addTask method in the end.

Answer (score 0):

use this please.

```
class AddTaskController extends GetxController {

    var _toDoTasksList = [].obs;
    List<TaskItem> get toDoTasksList => [..._toDoTasksList];

    addTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
    _toDoTasksList.add(taskItem);
  }

   removeTask(TaskItem taskItem) {
   _toDoTasksList.remove(taskItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with RxList and you want to force update the state of the page, you need to use yourRxList.refresh() to notify listeners about the changes.